# How do I modify the example json in swagger?

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I'm trying to modify the sample json shown to test in swagger if a POST works or doesn't work. From where should I modify this?
That is, I would have to modify the json that is displayed when we press "Try out".

[image]

To be more precise, the json to test the post is the following:

```
{
"Cliente": 0,
  "CantidadRegistros": 0,
  "TotalesPrimerVencimiento": 0,
  "TotalesSegundoVencimiento": 0,
  "Detalle": [
    {
      "Consorcio": 0,
      "UnidadFuncional": 0,
      "Periodo": "string",
      "Propietario": "string",
      "Ubicacion": "string",
      "Email": "string",
      "FechaPrimerVencimiento": "2021-12-15",
      "ImportePrimerVencimiento": 0,
      "FechaSegundoVencimiento": "2021-12-15",
      "ImporteSegundoVencimiento": 0,
      "CodigoDePagoElectronico": "string",
      "CodigoDeBarras": "string"
    }
  ]
}
```

What I would like to modify is the format in which the date is displayed. Currently it is dd-mm-yyyy and I want to modify it to dd/mm/yyyy

Tried modifying this with the following DisplayFormat code but it didn't work for me:

```
[JsonPropertyName("FechaSegundoVencimiento")]
[FromQuery(Name = "FechaSegundoVencimiento")]
[ModelBinder(BinderType = typeof(DateTimeModelBinder))]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public DateTime? DueDate2 { get; set; }
```

I hope your help! Thanks!

Comment: I've edited the tags on your question to mention [Swagger UI](https://swagger.io/tools/swagger-ui/), which I'm guessing is what this screenshot is of. The fact that the API uses C# and ASP.net doesn't seem to be relevant, so I've removed those tags. However, it would be good to [edit] in some more details of what exactly you want to do and what you've tried so far - remember that you've been staring at this problem for a while, but people reading your question have only the information you give them.

Comment: @IMSoP the ASP.NET/C# part _is_ relevant, their Swagger/OpenAPI docs are generated by an ASP.NET-specific library, Swashbuckle. Probably.

Comment: @CodeCaster Then they need to say so - which is why I left a comment after editing, so that they could clarify if necessary. The question simply said "where do I edit this?" and mentioned JSON and Swagger. For all I could tell, they're generating the documentation by parsing their source code using an awk script. Since they seem to agree with your mention of Swashbuckle, I've added that tag.

Comment: The example shows up as `yyyy-mm-dd` because that's the [expected format](https://spec.openapis.org/oas/v3.0.3.html#data-types) for `DataType.Date` in OpenAPI. If you want to use another date format, you need to change the annotations so that they generate those fields as just `type: string`. Or change your API to use `yyyy-mm-dd` instead.

Comment: Oh, okay. Now I understand better. And from where the API is modified so that it expects another format the DataType.DateTime @Helen ?

Comment: I'm not sure but you may need to tweak Swashbuckle's `ISchemaFilter`.

Answer (score 1):

The supported and out of the box way to do this, is by [using XML comments, generating documentation files on build and having Swashbuckle read these comments](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#include-descriptions-from-xml-comments):

Model:

```
public class Product
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The name of the product
    /// </summary>
    /// <example>Men's basketball shoes</example>
    public string Name { get; set; }

// ...
```

Startup:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", ...);

     var filePath = Path.Combine(System.AppContext.BaseDirectory, "Your.App.xml");
     c.IncludeXmlComments(filePath);
}
```

If memory serves me right, this generates one example per model property. So if you reuse models between different APIs and want different examples, you'll need to branch out to other libraries.

I have used [mattfrear/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Filters](https://github.com/mattfrear/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Filters#do-not-use-this-filter-unless-you-have-to), where you can annotate your methods with `[SwaggerRequestExample(typeof(...)]` and `[SwaggerResponseExample(typeof(...))]`, where `...` can provide an example object that will be serialized to JSON, but note that in various cases they recommend to use Swashbuckle's built-in way.

**However**, you say:

> Currently it is dd-mm-yyyy and I want to modify it to dd/mm/yyyy

Don't. There's no predefined date format for JSON, but most APIs accept ISO-8601(ish) formats by default. Don't go make that culture-specific.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot @CodeCaster ! I will be testing this and commenting on how it went.

Comment: Why do you recommend me not to change the date format?

Comment: Because that's a silly thing to do. JSON is a machine-readable format. If you want to format dates for humans, then do so when presenting that date to a human.

Comment: Sure, it is that I need that format so that a person can load their JSON by swagger. I modified my question.